# SQL distinct if previously occuring

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to collapse rows if a column has already appeared...

SQL Server - table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE Docs 
(
    Area varchar(max),
    RootFolder varchar(max),
    SubFolder varchar(max),
)
```

Raw data:

| Area | RootFolder | SubFolder |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | 12345 |  |
| One | 12345 | 6789 |
| One | 12345 | AAAAA |
| One | CCCCC |  |
| One | DDDDDD |  |
| One | DDDDDD | FFFFFF |
| One | DDDDDD | GGGGG |

I want:

| Area | RootFolder | SubFolder |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | 12345 | 6789 |
| One | 12345 | AAAAA |
| One | CCCCC |  |
| One | DDDDDD | FFFFFF |
| One | DDDDDD | GGGGG |

I've tried group bys and other window functions but I don't know how to get the output I want

Comment: Returned rows have no particular order: You must define how to determine "already".

Comment: @Bohemian see row 4 of the raw data, since it's unique I want to include it, then see row 5, I don't want that, because it's in row 6 and 7...

Comment: @znedw you're missing the point. Without an order by clause, the same query can return the same rows in a different order. Also, common solutions require ordering information. Or it is that you want to exclude rows where subfolder is blank/null, but only if other rows for the same rootfolder are present?

Comment: > it is that you want to exclude rows where subfolder is blank/null, but only if other rows for the same rootfolder are present. yes - exactly this

Comment: Well, I already guessed so looking at your data. But your explanation in the request is wrong. Unfortunately, this is the part that counts. If you want to write a query then specify exactly what data you want to see. Otherwise you will not be able to write the query. This means your main problem was not SQL here, but the step before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to show all rows that either are a subfolder or for which no subfolder exists.

```
select *
from docs
where subfolder is not null
or not exists
(
  select null
  from docs sub
  where sub.area = docs.area
  and sub.rootfolder = docs.rootfolder
  and sub.subfolder is not null
);
```

Comment: Thank you, adding distinct to the top SELECT has given me the results I want :)

Comment: This is weird. If you must add `DISTINCT`, then your table contains duplicate rows. Why do you allow duplicate rows in your table? What is the purpose of that?

Comment: There's another column named filename which is unique, I omitted for brevity but I'm not interested in it for this particular query 